# How to bind data from 4 different tables via EF to dropdownlist in view ?MVC4

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My exact requirement is i want to create a strongly typed view which displays the list say employee name from one table with empid & emp_name like that i have 4 tables where i need to bind the data to view Via RETURN (XYZ) .

In that XYZ i should have the complete prop's & data to pass to view and so i can bind respectively to my dropdownlist respectively .

I been trying over a day but stuck with dropdownlist binding , I check around 10+ articles nothing came up to solve my cause .

Home controller

```
public ActionResult stop()
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client ser_obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            IEnumerable<LobList> obj = ser_obj.GetData().ToList();  
 //i am getting list from WCF method (GETDATA ) which in turn gets from business  layer 
           return View(obj.ToList());

        }
```

IN VIEW :

```
Here : 
@model IEnumerable<entitymodel.LobList>
 <td>
                @foreach (var item in Model) 
                {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Modelitem=>item.LOB_NAME,new SelectList(Model,"lob_id","lob_name"))
                }
            </td>
```

When i remove foreach and try this is not at working but under foreach its working but to its functionality dropdowns are displaying duplicates

```
@model IEnumerable<entitymodel.LobList>
    <td>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m. ??????? ,new SelectList(Model,"lob_id","lob_name"))

        </td>
```

Initially i am unable to clear one dropdownlist not thinking to far ahead to bind 4 :(

Any help is appreciated .

Ty so such for your time in helping others

Comment: You should show the code that you've written so far.

Comment: sure just a moment i will edit my post